# DAX add column to show amount applied to sales order

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI that looks something like this:

| Document# | Created From | Amount | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV1234 | SO7654 | $600 |  |
| INV2345 | SO7654 | $200 |  |
| SO7654 |  | $1000 | Partially Filled |
| INV3456 | SO6543 | $500 |  |
| SO6543 |  | $500 | Filled |

I would like to add a column to show the total amount that has been invoiced against a sales order.

| Document# | Created From | Amount | Status | Amount Applied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV1234 | SO7654 | $600 |  |  |
| INV2345 | SO7654 | $200 |  |  |
| SO7654 |  | $1000 | Partially Filled | $800 |
| INV3456 | SO6543 | $500 |  |  |
| SO6543 |  | $500 | Filled | $500 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate as new DAX column:

```
    Amount Applied = 
var __curDoc = table[Document#]
    return
    calculate(sum('table'[Amount]), filter(all(table), table[Created From] = __curDoc  ))
```